# Standard LaTeX fonts, babel, and font encoding

Tags: fonts, pdftex, babel, font-encodings

I seem to have stumbled upon a clash between the standard (non-Latin Modern LaTeX) [fonts](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/), the L7x (Lithuanian) font encoding and the babel package. If try to use several languages (e.g., Lithuanian and English) in the document, or if I try to compile the entire thing in Lithuanian, I get something like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\linespread{1.05}  

\usepackage[L7x,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[lithuanian,english]{babel}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{english}

\begin{otherlanguage}{lithuanian}

Letter test: ĄČĘĖĮŠŲŪŽ ąčęėįšųūž 

Mikalojus Konstantinas Čiurlionis (1875 m. rugsėjo 22 d. Varėnoje (šiuo metu Senoji Varėna) --- 1911 m. balandžio 10 d. Pustelnike, netoli Varšuvos, palaidotas Vilniaus Rasų kapinėse) --- lietuvių kompozitorius, dailininkas, chorvedys, kultūros veikėjas. Čiurlionis vertinamas kaip žymiausias kada nors gyvenęs Lietuvos dailininkas ir kompozitorius. Tarp žinomiausių jo muzikinių darbų – simfoninės poemos ``Miške'' ir ``Jūra''. Iš dailės darbų populiariausi: ``Pasaka. Karaliai'', ``Rex'', Piramidžių ir Žvaigždžių sonatos. XX a. tarpukariu pavardės linksniavimas iš dalies skyrėsi nuo dabartinio: Čiurlionis--Čiurlionies ir t. t.

\end{otherlanguage}

Letter test: ĄČĘĖĮŠŲŪŽ ąčęėįšųūž 

Mikalojus Konstantinas Čiurlionis (Polish: Mikołaj Konstanty Czurlanis; 22 September [O.S. 10 September] 1875 ---10 April [O.S. 28 March] 1911) was a Lithuanian painter, composer and writer. Čiurlionis contributed to symbolism and art nouveau and was representative of the fin de siècle epoch. He has been considered one of the pioneers of abstract art in Europe.[2] During his short life he composed about 400 pieces of music and created about 300 paintings, as well as many literary works and poems. The majority of his paintings are housed in the M. K. Čiurlionis National Art Museum in Kaunas, Lithuania. His works have had a profound influence on modern Lithuanian culture. The asteroid 2420 Čiurlionis is named after him.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Essentially, the entire Lithuanian (L7x encoded) part of text reverts back to Latin Modern. With `\usepackage[lithuanian]{babel}` alone, the font does not change anywhere in the text. The text was compiled with pdfLaTeX (Texworks), if that makes any difference.

Can this package clash be fixed somehow (preferably, without reverting to XeLaTeX)?

Comment: With lithuanian alone (almost) everything is in latin modern too. There are no supporting files for palatino for L7x. If you need this font encoding you will have either to use another basefont or create the necessary palatino files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're lucky: TeX Gyre Pagella supports the L7x encoding.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{tgpagella}
\linespread{1.05}  

\usepackage[L7x,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[lithuanian,english]{babel}
\renewcommand{\ltfamily}{\familydefault}

\begin{document}

\begin{otherlanguage}{lithuanian}

Letter test: ĄČĘĖĮŠŲŪŽ ąčęėįšųūž 

Mikalojus Konstantinas Čiurlionis (1875 m. rugsėjo 22 d. Varėnoje 
(šiuo metu Senoji Varėna) --- 1911 m. balandžio 10 d. Pustelnike, 
netoli Varšuvos, palaidotas Vilniaus Rasų kapinėse) --- lietuvių 
kompozitorius, dailininkas, chorvedys, kultūros veikėjas. Čiurlionis 
vertinamas kaip žymiausias kada nors gyvenęs Lietuvos dailininkas ir 
kompozitorius. Tarp žinomiausių jo muzikinių darbų – simfoninės poemos 
``Miške'' ir ``Jūra''. Iš dailės darbų populiariausi: ``Pasaka. 
Karaliai'', ``Rex'', Piramidžių ir Žvaigždžių sonatos. XX a. tarpukariu 
pavardės linksniavimas iš dalies skyrėsi nuo dabartinio: 
Čiurlionis--Čiurlionies ir t. t.

\end{otherlanguage}

Letter test: ĄČĘĖĮŠŲŪŽ ąčęėįšųūž 

Mikalojus Konstantinas Čiurlionis (1875 m. rugsėjo 22 d. Varėnoje 
(šiuo metu Senoji Varėna) --- 1911 m. balandžio 10 d. Pustelnike, 
netoli Varšuvos, palaidotas Vilniaus Rasų kapinėse) --- lietuvių 
kompozitorius, dailininkas, chorvedys, kultūros veikėjas. Čiurlionis 
vertinamas kaip žymiausias kada nors gyvenęs Lietuvos dailininkas ir 
kompozitorius. Tarp žinomiausių jo muzikinių darbų – simfoninės poemos 
``Miške'' ir ``Jūra''. Iš dailės darbų populiariausi: ``Pasaka. 
Karaliai'', ``Rex'', Piramidžių ir Žvaigždžių sonatos. XX a. tarpukariu 
pavardės linksniavimas iš dalies skyrėsi nuo dabartinio: 
Čiurlionis--Čiurlionies ir t. t.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! This definitely seems to do the trick. Is there an analogous package for any of the Garamond-style fonts (a la {garamondx} or [urw-garamond]{mathdesign})?

Comment: @user107355 As far as I know, only the TeX Gyre fonts (among which Latin Modern) support the L7x encoding.